# How io_service matches a completion event with a completion handler

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have been reading boost asio docs, Specifically about Proactor design.

when I came across this tittle

**The Proactor Design Pattern: Concurrency Without Threads**

What I sort of understand is, The users of asio don't need to create additional threads for doing an asynchronous IO as threads are already prevail in the form of  Asynchronous Operation Processor in this pattern.

So just to confirm the io_service is going to act as a proactor(fetch the completion event and dispatch it to the completion handler)

Whenever an async process got initiated it is going to take care by a background thread.

`socket.async_connect(server_endpoint, your_completion_handler);`

Is the below sequence correct?

1) Connect operation going to be handled by a thread.

2) Completion_handler going to be pushed into some queue (or any DS)?.

3) Once the async_connect has finished, It's result/Errorcode will be placed in a completion event queue.

4) The proactor(io_service?)fetch the completion event maps it to the handler

I just wonder how this mapping has been done, As the Asynchronous Operation Processor has made out of threads(doesn't it ?) anything that finishes first will trigger a completion event and how the `io_service` will know which completion handler should be called for this event and which one for that event( I thought of looking into the implementation, But to me it seems a bit heavy now.)

Answer (score 1):

`io_service` is basically a function queue. When you instantiate your `socket`, you pass a reference of `io_service` to it. Now when you do the call:

```
socket.async_connect(server_endpoint, your_completion_handler);
```

You're starting an asynchronous operation, where ASIO pushes a synchronous function to `io_service`, which is your function queue. The function that ASIO pushes to `io_service` contains your handler. When the time comes, `io_service` pops an element (a function) from the queue and does the operation for you, and finally calls your handler with the result from that operation.

A little more info on queuing: If you start the `io_service` object (with `io_service::run()`) in one thread, then you'll have a real serial queue where everything is executed in order. On the other hand, if you call `io_service::run()` on multiple threads, the queue will be distributed on these threads. Non-blocking thread-safety can be achieved using ASIO's `strand`.

Comment: I agree with `strand` which actually makes the completion event queue as thread safety when we have multiple proactors to watch for  a completion event.TBH `The function that ASIO pushes to io_service contains your handler` I had this same thought and  based on what has been said we have only one queue which is actually a task queue and once a thread pops the task it executes it and will call it's associated handler which is an another parameter. Is that right?

Comment: @Explorer_N Yes, once a task its finished, the associated handler will be called, which is a parameter. I repeated what you said because I want to emphasize that the handler is called after the task is completed.

Comment: You know it's just a  thought , Doesn't it seems contrary to what the have as a diagram here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html if you look at'em they have showed a separate queue called  `Completion Event Queue`  where the proactor will watch for an event and dispatch it to the handler after converting the result into a proper Error code, So to me it's like the async operation and the handler has been separated and got merged by a proactor using a proper dispatch.

Comment: @Explorer_N It sounds to me that this is an implementation detail. Why does that matter? And to answer your question, I have to say I'm not an expert in boost implementations, but just with how to use it.

Comment: Because I have a feeling that People who wish to see the implementation will create a wrong(may be?) mental model as I did and looks for things that doesn't exist.

Comment: But even with the diagram for people who wish to explain Asio to others , don't they get questions like how the event and handler mapping has been done?

Comment: @Explorer_N Honestly I never wondered about it. Like I said, to me it's an implementation detail, whether it's a parameter, or there's another object that passes them. To me as a user, it doesn't make a difference. However, thank you for this info. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Just a thought, If this question makes sense can we get this to the author or to any persons who knows what actually goes into the implementation.

Comment: TBH, I am actually overwhelmed when I look at the implementation.

Comment: @Explorer_N You're not alone. The implementation is overwhelming. Boost is a very advanced library. You have to make a big effort to understand it. You can visit ASIO homepage [here](http://think-async.com/). The author's name is Chris Kohlhoff.

Comment: The Quantum Physicist, Appreciate thanks for the link, I had been through this and now trying to dig the implementation.

Comment: Hey without knowing the implementation detail how can you said this `The function that ASIO pushes to io_service contains your handler`?

Comment: @Explorer_N It's from previous discussions and from books I read when I first learned this. This is how I know it, but I may be wrong.